# How to aggregate two objects from same referenced table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

So, I have a table user which belongs to member table.

User table is:

```
id, firstName, lastName
```

Member table is: where creatorId also belongs to user table.

```
id, userId, creatorId
```

I'm trying to get the userId which has the user details and creatorId which has the user details too using the aggregrate.

```
SELECT
member.id,
    json_agg(json_build_object('userId', user.id, 'firstName', user.firstName)) AS user,
    json_agg(json_build_object('userId', c.id, 'firstName', c.firstName)) AS creator

FROM
    member
    INNER JOIN user u ON member.userId = u.id
    INNER JOIN user c ON member.creatorId = user.id
GROUP BY
    am.id
```

I also want to include the creator firstName and lastName but Im not sure how to do that. Please can anyone help.

Comment: You need different table aliases for the 3 member instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT m.id,
       json_agg(json_build_object('userId', mu.id, 'firstName', mu.firstName)) AS user,
       json_agg(json_build_object('creatorId', mc.id, 'firstName', mc.firstName)) AS creator
FROM member m INNER JOIN
     member mu
     ON m.userId = mu.id INNER JOIN
     member mc
     ON m.creatorId = mc.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

That said, I doubt that aggregation is needed.  Presumably, `id` is the primary key.  Also, you might want `LEFT JOIN`, just in case either field is `NULL`.  So:

```
SELECT m.id,
       json_build_object('userId', mu.id, 'firstName', mu.firstName) AS user,
       json_build_object('creatorId', mc.id, 'firstName', mc.firstName) AS creator
FROM member m LEFT JOIN
     member mu
     ON m.userId = mu.id LEFT JOIN
     member mc
     ON m.creatorId = mc.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This just changes around some of the alias names.  You have two JOINS on 'user', so you should always qualify your references with the proper alias.

```
SELECT
   m.id,
   json_agg(json_build_object('userId', u.id, 'firstName', u.firstName)) AS user,
   json_agg(json_build_object('userId', c.id, 'firstName', c.firstName)) AS creator

FROM member as m
   INNER JOIN user u ON m.userId = u.id
   INNER JOIN user c ON m.creatorId = c.id -- this had user.id instead of c.id
GROUP BY
    m.id
```